# parse / convert cookie to JSON format

Tags: javascript

Have we any javascript library or regex to parse / convert cookies to JSON format?

Some cookies like this:

```
cookie=referer=example.com/post?id=22;bcomID=8075; subreturn=example&fuzzy=true&ct=null&autobounce=true; JSESSIONID=6D20570E1EB; mbox=session
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var cookie = "referer=example.com/post?id=22;bcomID=8075; subreturn=example&fuzzy=true&ct=null&autobounce=true; JSESSIONID=6D20570E1EB; mbox=session";
var output = {};
cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function(pair) {
  pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);
  output[pair[0]] = pair.splice(1).join('=');
});
var json = JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);
console.log(json);
```

**EDIT:**

If the cookie have %NUM characters you can wrap name and value with `decodeURIComponent`:

```
var output = {};
cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function(pair) {
  pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);
  var name = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
  var value = decodeURIComponent(pair.splice(1).join('='));
  output[name] = value;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little different approach that can extract all cookie (name, value) pairs. Notice the test case. Most of the available cookie parsers will fail to parse this string properly.

```js
function extractCookies(cookieStr) {
  return cookieStr
    .match(/(^|(?<=, ))[^=;,]+=[^;]+/g)
    .map(cookie => cookie.split('=').map(v => v.trim()))
    .filter(v => v[0].length && v[1].length)
    .reduce((builder, cur) => {
      builder[cur[0]] = cur[1]
      return builder
    }, {})
}

var testCase = '__cfduid=da48fc97c9ea6147d5534503f5337db821534343165; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-19 14:26:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.foobar.com; HttpOnly, XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Imx3TXJFZ013QVRiXC9mUzFMXC9uM2NzQT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ5Z2V2SVJRUlpKRmQ0c0xCU0VWUDBGVzduWnBxVlwvaVhVTnlSbzdnTnJkdzlNd0M2KzFDZWVzQ3lZT1N6RkpJdkZuM0w4MkMraE5SWDN1XC9xUmlNNDJRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3MmE4YzEwYTY5ZGI5NTIyNWMyZTBmM2Q0YTlhZGE3Mzk2MzYyMmI1NGZiYWFmNjBlMjgxMTZjMzFkOGU3N2UxIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 15-Aug-2018 16:26:05 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/, laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikp2ckE5ME5KRFU4TlFOc0xxVUZXR2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRWRcLzRMdFJLMEM2U2dEdTdUN1FcL2w2WGZ5eGJ1VmF2ZHJYd2JoVjUzSHBWQlkzYmIzWWRzUllMcEt0Sjk3OVlaeGRLTWozNFJyVDBPZkxuT3RnVUY2dz09IiwibWFjIjoiYzg1OGY3MGY4NTEzMmJlY2E3MjhlOGM5NTM4ZmY1MjdlYjc4YjIyOTQyODFiYjdlNDcyMzY3NTQzNGRkYTU3MiJ9; expires=Wed, 15-Aug-2018 16:26:05 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly';

console.log(extractCookies(testCase));
```

My test case:

> __cfduid=da48fc97c9ea6147d5534503f5337db821534343165; expires=Thu, 15-Aug-19 14:26:05 GMT; path=/; domain=.foobar.com; HttpOnly, XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Imx3TXJFZ013QVRiXC9mUzFMXC9uM2NzQT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ5Z2V2SVJRUlpKRmQ0c0xCU0VWUDBGVzduWnBxVlwvaVhVTnlSbzdnTnJkdzlNd0M2KzFDZWVzQ3lZT1N6RkpJdkZuM0w4MkMraE5SWDN1XC9xUmlNNDJRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3MmE4YzEwYTY5ZGI5NTIyNWMyZTBmM2Q0YTlhZGE3Mzk2MzYyMmI1NGZiYWFmNjBlMjgxMTZjMzFkOGU3N2UxIn0%3D; expires=Wed, 15-Aug-2018 16:26:05 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/, laravel_session=eyJpdiI6Ikp2ckE5ME5KRFU4TlFOc0xxVUZXR2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRWRcLzRMdFJLMEM2U2dEdTdUN1FcL2w2WGZ5eGJ1VmF2ZHJYd2JoVjUzSHBWQlkzYmIzWWRzUllMcEt0Sjk3OVlaeGRLTWozNFJyVDBPZkxuT3RnVUY2dz09IiwibWFjIjoiYzg1OGY3MGY4NTEzMmJlY2E3MjhlOGM5NTM4ZmY1MjdlYjc4YjIyOTQyODFiYjdlNDcyMzY3NTQzNGRkYTU3MiJ9; expires=Wed, 15-Aug-2018 16:26:05 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly

Expected output:

```
{
    "__cfduid": "da48fc97c9ea6147d5534503f5337db821534343165",
    "XSRF-TOKEN": "eyJpdiI6Imx3TXJFZ013QVRiXC9mUzFMXC9uM2NzQT09IiwidmFsdWUiOiJ5Z2V2SVJRUlpKRmQ0c0xCU0VWUDBGVzduWnBxVlwvaVhVTnlSbzdnTnJkdzlNd0M2KzFDZWVzQ3lZT1N6RkpJdkZuM0w4MkMraE5SWDN1XC9xUmlNNDJRPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3MmE4YzEwYTY5ZGI5NTIyNWMyZTBmM2Q0YTlhZGE3Mzk2MzYyMmI1NGZiYWFmNjBlMjgxMTZjMzFkOGU3N2UxIn0%3D",
    "laravel_session": "eyJpdiI6Ikp2ckE5ME5KRFU4TlFOc0xxVUZXR2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiRWRcLzRMdFJLMEM2U2dEdTdUN1FcL2w2WGZ5eGJ1VmF2ZHJYd2JoVjUzSHBWQlkzYmIzWWRzUllMcEt0Sjk3OVlaeGRLTWozNFJyVDBPZkxuT3RnVUY2dz09IiwibWFjIjoiYzg1OGY3MGY4NTEzMmJlY2E3MjhlOGM5NTM4ZmY1MjdlYjc4YjIyOTQyODFiYjdlNDcyMzY3NTQzNGRkYTU3MiJ9"
}
```

Comment: don't seems to work without expire '  'io=t8Ta2Obl0XV8mRnRAAAA; ' +
    'connect.sid=s%3Ao_AhA1ck602RHpublpjxueZq18655BDE.1GBBnz19Vrz6qv%2F2tXMOUPlh9ZwTZfCMJlwnpV4RFYw' only the first is detected

Comment: I think I posted this code with the intention to parse response cookies instead of request cookies. the formats are different for these two. there are no expire date in request cookies. and delimiters are semicolons instead of commas

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```js
let cookie = 'displayName=Miss Jane; id=jane; email=jane@blow.com'
cookie = cookie.split("; ");
let obj = {};
cookie.forEach((item,index) => {
  let i = item.split("=");
  obj[i[0]]=i[1];
});
console.log(obj.id);
```