# How to click on devtools console tab with Selenium and python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this code:

```
async def acess_all():                         
 def acess_localhost():                               
  option = Options()                            
  option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")       
  option.debugger_Address="127.0.0.1:8081"    
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)     
  driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081")        
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)            
  wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.item'))).click()                 
 try:                                           
  t =  threading.Thread(target=get_infos)        
  t.start()                                     
  os.system("chromium --remote-debugging-port=8081 https://google.com")                    
 except:                                        
  print("Error!")
```

**What I need:**

Guys, as you can see, this code opens the Chrome browser on the Google page, and my Selenium code opens the browser on localhost because it's accessing where the remote-debbuging address points to, but I can't access the console tab of devtools, I need to access this tab using Selenium and run a javascript command to copy the cookie in json format, but I can't, how can I access the devtools console tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've figured out a way to run a javascript command in the console and get a return value (using selenium, as in the question).

*Note:* I'm running this on a Windows computer, but the idea should remain the same on a different operating system. You might have to tweak a few things in this code. Also, **all Chrome sessions have to be closed beforehand to get this to work.**

Ok, unless I interpreted your question wrong (tell me if I did), this is the basic order of the things you want you want to happen when:

1. Open the regular chrome browser (by regular, I mean not selenium, but regular chrome.exe or Google Chrome.app) to google.com and set the debugging port (which I assume is what you're doing when you run this command: `chromium --remote-debugging-port=8081 https://google.com`)
2. Open Chromedriver (Selenium) and go to the locally-hosted debugger window at 127.0.0.1:8081
3. Select the  "Google" window option in the list of available windows at 127.0.0.1:8081 [image]
4. Once the devtools window opens, move to the Console tab
5. Finally, run some Javascript in the Console's input box and somehow get a return value for a cookie

You already did the first few items (1-3) in your code but you needed help figuring out the rest. I think I've found a way to do it.

So assuming that you already opened the google.com window on the Chrome browser *and* the 127.0.0.1:8081 window on localhost, all you need to do now is access the Console.
Here's what my chromedriver (selenium) browser screen looks like at this point, just for reference.
[image: show the window before clicking anything]

We'll start by waiting until a specific element (devtools-elements-breadcrumbs) has loaded on the page. We wait for this so we are sure that the page is loaded enough to navigate. I found this element by looking at the driver page_source. Here's how we wait for it:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "devtools-elements-breadcrumbs")))
```

Once the breadcrumb element is located we can move to the console window by sending a [shortcut](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/shortcuts/) to the chromedriver browser telling it to move right one tab in the Inspector window (to Console). The command is `Control + ]` (Windows/Linux) or `Command + ]` (Mac), to go to the next panel. This is how we send that shortcut to the selenium window (once again, using Windows):

```
click_console = ActionChains(driver)
click_console.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(']').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

or on a Mac,

```
click_console = ActionChains(driver)
click_console.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys(']').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
```

After moving to the Console, we now have to wait for the console area to load, so we wait for all the CodeMirror class elements (once again, found using driver.page_source)

```
# wait for console area to open
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "CodeMirror")))
```

Now the last thing to do is to send the javascript command to the console. In this example, I'm searching for the APISID cookie.

```
cookie_name = "SEARCH_SAMESITE"
# javascript find the cookie
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/59603055/11073064
js_command = '(\"; \" + document.cookie).split(\"; {}\").pop().split(\';\').shift();'.format(cookie_name)
# send the command to the selenium webbrowser
send_js_command = ActionChains(driver)
send_js_command.send_keys(js_command, Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

[image: show the console after running the javascript]
and to get the value outputted in the console after you run that command:

```
# wait for return value span tag to be found
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.object-value-string.source-code')))
value = element.text
driver.close()
```

Here's the full code I used (on Windows).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import threading
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os


def start_chrome_browser_with_debug():
    # this is the path to your regular google chrome browser, not selenium chromedriver
    # note the chrome.exe, not chromedriver.exe. 
    # point the path to your regular chrome browser
    os.system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=8081 https://google.com')


cookie_name = "SEARCH_SAMESITE"
js_command = '(\"; \" + document.cookie).split(\"; {}\").pop().split(\';\').shift();'.format(cookie_name)

chrome_browser = threading.Thread(target=start_chrome_browser_with_debug)
chrome_browser.start()

option = Options()
option.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
option.debugger_Address = "127.0.0.1:8081"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8081")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.item'))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "devtools-elements-breadcrumbs")))
click_console = ActionChains(driver)
click_console.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(']').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "CodeMirror")))
send_js_command = ActionChains(driver)
send_js_command.send_keys(js_command, Keys.ENTER).perform()
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.object-value-string.source-code')))
value = element.text
driver.close()
os.system('taskkill  /F /IM chrome.exe /T')
print(value)
```

Comment: I cannot get the `devtools-elements-breadcrumbs`. What version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: interesting. I'm using 92.0.4515.131. That element probably isn't the only one that can be used to check if the console is loaded. Alternatively, time.sleep(5) or something like that also works for me

Comment: I'm using the same Chrome version.  I get this error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"devtools-elements-breadcrumbs"}`

Comment: this might be the wrong question, but are you searching for `devtools-elements-breadcrumbs` by tag name? I think the error you gave me says that the you searched for it by css selector (method: css selector). It is actually a tag (<devtools-elements-breadcrumbs>) that can be found using `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "devtools-elements-breadcrumbs")))`. Could you share the code you're using to search for the element? Is it the same as that?

Comment: I tried your wait.until code, which didn't work. I also tried driver.find_element_by_tag_name , which threw the error.  I'm using a MAC, so I'm trying to port your code to work correctly in this OS.

Comment: I appreciate it. If everything up to that point is working and you're in the selenium dev tools window, try using either *time.sleep* instead or look at the driver.page_source (which I got after sleeping for five seconds after the dev tools window is opened). It could be that there's a naming difference or that the element doesn't exist on the page you're on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235900/discussion-between-twiddler-and-life-is-complex).

Comment: Man, thank you very much, I had the same idea as you, but I was almost finished in a not so simple way, but thanks, you gave me a few hours of trying

Comment: @twiddler I'm just having a little doubt, instead of using the Google page I used the discord.com page, and I noticed that it returns "locale=pt-BR", How can I get the cookie?  I need to copy the cookie with devtool, and in json format

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted that part of your question. Your comment makes it seem like you want all the cookie values (hence json) and not just a specific one. You could change the code so that `js_command = 'var cookie=document.cookie;var output={};cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/).forEach(function(pair) {pair = pair.split(/\s*=\s*/);output[pair[0]] = pair.splice(1).join(\'=\');}); JSON.stringify(output, null, 4);'` ([look here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30138594/parse-convert-cookie-to-json-format)) and then load the output into a dictionary using json.loads.

Comment: The above parses the document.cookie string into json, as you asked. Alternatively you could just set `js_command='document.cookie'` and find a way to convert the output of my code into json (using python instead of javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can execute the javascript command by selenium itself :

```
driver.execute_script("some javascript code here");
```

Comment: but this question is about clicking on `Dev tool console`

Comment: I think you can use key bindings in selenium try `send_keys()` functions,besides, try both the `options.add_argument("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");` and `send_keys()`

Comment: @Erkin If you run my code you will see devtools, the problem is that if you press F12 you will see that you have 2 devtools, so it wouldn't work, and even if it did it would only open devtools

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Selenium to interact with the dev tools console, however you don't need it to get the cookies, just use `get_cookies()` from the `webdriver` and convert it to json using `json.dumps()`

```
import json

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
js = json.dumps(cookies)
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make this work on a Mac using only Python and Selenium. However, I found a solution that works if I use pyautogui in addition.

I'm working on a file, duals7.svg, saved locally. I want to be able to open it, play with it and watch what happens at the Javascript developer console in Chrome.

The script below does exactly what I want:

```
# chrome.py

# https://www.browserstack.com/guide/python-selenium-to-run-web-automation-test
# https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-do-i-pass-options-to-the-selenium-chrome-driver-using-python
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311191/how-to-open-chrome-developer-console-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java
# https://towardsdatascience.com/controlling-the-web-with-python-6fceb22c5f08

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

import pyautogui 

op     = webdriver.ChromeOptions ()
op.add_argument ('--allow-file-access-from-files')
op.add_argument ('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')

driver = webdriver.Chrome (options=op)
driver.get ('file:///Users/murray/projects/warp/dual7.svg')

console = (850, 175)

pyautogui.moveTo (console [0], console [1], duration = 0.5)
pyautogui.click (console [0], console [1])
```

(I don't think the pyautogui.moveTo command is needed. Including it allows me to watch the mouse move, which I like.)

When I run it (python chrome.py), I see my svg "app" in Chrome with the Javascript dev console open:

[image: running the script gives this]

The coordinates of the console button were determined by trial and error. Please forgive the aesthetics of the app: it'll look nice when it's done.

When I interact with my "app" I see my console.log () debugging messages.

If you're interested, the app is being modified from

```
/* elliptic-mesh.js
 *
 * generates a structured mesh bounded by four splines by
 * solving the elliptic Laplace equation
 *
 * For more info see:
 * http://www.particleincell.com/2012/online-meshing-example/
 * http://www.particleincell.com/2012/bezier-splines/ 
 *
 * Lubos Brieda, Particle In Cell Consulting LLC, 2012
 * you may freely use this algorithm in your codes but whenever possible
 * please include a link/reference to the source article
 */
```

My version generalizes Dr. Brieda's code a bit, adds some debugging statements, and will add save and load options.